# ncurses form is not allocating: unkown error

Tags: c, forms, ncurses

I am using ncurses to generate a form in a window but form is not being allocated, by using assert I confirmed that but I don't know the reason why this is happening , and also when I used perror then it shows `unknown error`.

Here is the code..

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <form.h>
#include <assert.h>

WINDOW *win_des;
FORM *form;
FIELD *fields[3];

void init_form()
{
    ui.if_form =1;
    // allocate fields , odd: fixed , even: editable...
    fields[0] = new_field(1, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    fields[1] = new_field(1, 20, 0, 15, 0, 0);
    fields[2] = NULL;
    assert(fields[0] != NULL && fields[1] != NULL  );
    set_field_buffer(fields[0], 0, "label1");
    set_field_buffer(fields[1], 0, "val1");
    set_field_opts(fields[0], O_VISIBLE | O_PUBLIC | O_AUTOSKIP);
    set_field_opts(fields[1], O_VISIBLE | O_PUBLIC | O_EDIT | O_ACTIVE);
    set_field_back(fields[1], A_REVERSE|A_BOLD);
    form = new_form(fields);

    keypad(win_des, true);
    form = new_form(fields);

    assert(form !=NULL);
    set_form_win(form, win_des);
    set_form_sub(form, derwin(win_des, 20, 100, 1, 1));
    post_form(form);

    refresh();
    wrefresh(win_des);

}

int main(void)
{
win_des = newwin(LINES, COLS, 0, 0);
box(win_des,0,0);
refresh();
wrefresh(win_des);
init_form();
return 0;
}
```

This is not working, and I am trying this code on the basis of this example [here](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/#OTHERLIB).
I know I also have to make form driver through which I will be moving cursor but initial it is not printing fields and hence crashing.

compiling with  `gcc my_form.c -lncurses -lform -o myform`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two problems:

1. You do not seem to be calling `initscr()`. You should call this before any other curses routine in `main`
2. You are calling `new_form` twice. Remove the second call.

Comment: yeah, i fixed that but still same problem.. :(